# How to convert arrays in Options API to Composition API in vue3?

Tags: vuejs3

I am converting working code from the Options API to Compostion API. I know that (for example) `this.myVar` becomes `myVar.value` but I'm confused by variables that don't appear to be defined!

```
handleDragEndItem() {
      if (this.originalList === this.futureList) {
        this.movingItem = this[this.futureList][this.originalIndex];
        this.futureItem = this[this.futureList][this.futureIndex];

        if (this.movingItem && this.futureItem) {
          let _list = Object.assign([], this[this.futureList]);
          _list[this.futureIndex] = this.movingItem;
          _list[this.originalIndex] = this.futureItem;
          this[this.futureList] = _list;
        }
      } else {...
```

There's no definition for `originalList`, `futureList` etc in the [original code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-app-zspw1h?file=src%2FApp.vue). This function is called as an event handler for a drag operation on a list, an example of which I have defined as a `ref` like this:

```
  const list1= ref( [
    { name: ' abcd', id: 0, style: { background: 'gold' } },
    { name: ' Tahu', id: 1, style: { background: 'red', color: 'yellow' },  },
    { name: ' Kopa', id: 2, style: { background: 'white' } },
    { name: ' Anak', id: 3,  style: { background: 'black', color: 'yellow' },  },
  ]);
```

I've tried defining vars for `originalList`, `futureList` etc but I'm sure that's not the correct thing to do. And I'm totally confused by trying to convert lines like `this.movingItem = this[this.futureList][this.originalIndex];`

Any help with conversion appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It works because `handleMoveItem` is called before `handleDragEndItem`, and since `this` is an object, there's nothing preventing you from adding properties to it that weren't there before (and then when `handleDragEndItem` is called, the properties exist), but it seems like bad practice to me. Just like using `document.querySelector` instead of Vue refs, and a couple of other things.

Apart from that, the vue.draggable library you're using hasn't been maintained in years and has its fair share of issues. [This one](https://github.com/MaxLeiter/sortablejs-vue3) seems like a reasonable alternative.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'm now playing with `sortablejs-vue` and it may be the solution. However I have to work out how to move items between lists with this library, and also how to use the `swap` plugin, the 'using plugins` section is giving me some errors (suggesting I addd a .ts file, which I don't understand, and that `import` cannot be used after ` SortableJs.mount(new Swap());` )

Comment: OK, items between lists just needs `group` defined in options. And the library works on mobile which is great. So just need now to work out how to plug in the `swap`